# Transparent activity not visible when we override home button action

Tags: android

I am working in an android application and my scenario is to show a transparent activity above an activity and I have successfully implemented it in by adding

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`

in my manifest in that activity. But also I want to override my android device hardware home button. So to that I have overridden the key events `dispatchKeyEvent` and `onAttachedToWindow` and I have successfully implemented that. But when I have overridden the home button keys this transparent activity is not visible. The code that I used to override the the home key events are

:

```
@Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        onAttachedToWindow();

        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {

            // if Home button is pressed EntryValidationActivity called
            SharescreenActivity.this.finish();
            Intent screenLockIntent = new Intent(SharescreenActivity.this,
                    EntryValidationActivity.class);
            startActivity(screenLockIntent);
            this.moveTaskToBack(true);
            return true;
        } else
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }


 @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {

        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);
        //this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

    }
```

Any solution to work these both together. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Home key cant be overriden, explore more on home key override funcion.

Comment: But I was able to override the home key event by the code described above..Please check that code. But it is not possible in all versions..